# Outer measure and Caratheodory's criterion

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $m^*$ is an outer measure in Caratheodory's sense on the space $X$, which satisfies $m^*(\emptyset)=0$, $A\subseteq B\implies m^*(A)\le m^*(B)$, and $m^*(\bigcup_n A_n)\le\sum m^*(A_n)$. We define $E$ measurable iff $m^*(E\cap A)+m^*(E^c\cap A)=m^*(A)$ for all $A\subseteq X$, and denote $m(E)=m^*(E)$. Is it true that $m^*$ is always really an outer measure, i.e.
$$m^*(A)=\inf\{\,m(E)\,\vert\,\text{measurable }E\supseteq A\,\}$$
If not, can we put some simple axioms to $m^*$ such that the preceding equality takes place?

I don't know any example of outer measure except Lebesgue outer measure, so I need some help. Thanks.

Comment: Good question. I cannot answer right now but I remember that I have seen this in the old book in measure theory by Munroe, in the chapter devoted to the Caratheodory construction.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Did you mean Munroe's GTM89 *Introduction to Measure Theory and Integration*? I've looked up and found nothing about this, but a discussion on the agreement of premeasure and the corresponding outer-measure.

Comment: I don't know what GTM89 refers to, but that seems to be the book. I was referring to Theorem 12.4 of page 99. It is relevant because the set function $\mu_0^\star$ defined there is exactly the right hand side of the identity you are trying to prove (i.e. $\mu_0^\star=\inf \{ \mu(E)\: A\subset E\, E\ \text{measurable}\}$).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Good. I took the wrong book so I didn't reach the same content. Now I borrowed the right book and found that the measure satisfying the condition I listed in the original post is just so-called *regular outer measure* in Munroe's book. Please post an answer filling the details and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I think that being "regular" is a stronger condition for a outer measure, corresponding to the fact that the "inf" in your formula is really a "min". That is, a outer measure is regular iff any set $A$ is contained in a measurable set $E$ such that $\mu(E)=\mu^\star(A)$ (I am using different symbols for measure and outer measure to remark that $E$ is measurable, but let's keep in mind that $\mu^\star\equiv \mu$ on measurable sets).

Comment: Anyway, AFAIK, non-regular outer measures are not really interesting.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro $\inf$ in my expression is really $\min$, i.e. if my expression of $m^*(A)$ is right, then it should be a regular measure, since suppose $m(E_n)\le m^*(A)+1/n$ and $E_n\supseteq A$, then consider $E=\bigcap_n E_n$. Since $E\supseteq A$, we have $m(E)\ge m^*(A)$, but $m(E)\le m(E_n)\le m^*(A)+1/n$, thus $m(E)=m^*(A)$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Generally, if $\mathcal A$ is a collection of subsets closed under countable intersection, then there's $A_0\in\mathcal A$ such that $m^*(A_0)=\alpha=\inf_{A\in\mathcal A} m(A)$. We again choose $A_n$ such that $m^*(A_n)\ge\alpha+1/n$, then let $A_0=\bigcap_n A_n\in\mathcal A$ and by def $m^*(A_0)\ge\alpha$, but $m^*(A_0)\le m^*(A_n)\le\alpha+1/n$.

Comment: I finally posted my answer, trying to fill in some details. It has been instructive. Please let me know if you find it satisfactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only outer measures for which your condition holds are the so-called *regular* outer measures $^{[1]}$, that is, the ones for which every set $A\subset X$ admits a measurable set $E$ such that $A\subset E$ and $m^\star(A)=m(E)$. (In Munroe's book *Introduction to measure and integration*, such a set $E$ is called a *measurable cover* for $A$.)

To prove this assertion we observe that for a regular outer measure the following infimum 
$$\tag{1}\inf \left\{ m(E)\ :\ A\subset E,\ E\text{ is measurable}\right\}$$
is attained at any measurable cover $E$ and $m(E)=m^\star(A)$, by definition. Conversely, if $m^\star(A)$ is given by (1), then$^{[2]}$ we can take a shrinking sequence $E_n$ of measurable sets containing $A$ and such that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} m(E_n)=m^\star(A).$$
Then $E=\cap_n E_n$ is a measurable cover for $A$ and $m^\star$ is regular.

Not every outer measure is regular. As an example, take a set $\Omega$ containing at least two element and define 
\begin{equation}
m^\star(E)=
\begin{cases}
0, & E=\varnothing \\
1, & E\subsetneq \Omega \\
1+\frac{1}{2}, & E=\Omega.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
This defines an outer measure such that the class of measurable sets is reduced to the trivial sigma algebra $\{\varnothing, \Omega\}$, so any proper subset of $\Omega$ has no measurable cover.

It is interesting to note that the measure $m$ associated to $m^\star$ is
\begin{equation}
m(E)=\begin{cases} 
0, & E=\varnothing\\
1+\frac{1}{2}, & E=\Omega,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and applying the method outlined in [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/742494/8157), which is denoted in Munroe's book as a (special case of) *Method I*, one gets the outer measure 
\begin{equation}
m^\star_0(E)=\begin{cases} 
0, & E=\varnothing \\
1+\frac{1}{2}, & E\subset \Omega.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
which is different from the original outer measure $m^\star$.

This phenomenon explains the terminology *regular*. Regular outer measures are those for which the application of Method I to the induced measure yields the original outer measure. This is the content of Theorem 12.4 at page 99 of Munroe's book.

---

$^{[1]}$ Not to be confused with [the concept of regularity of measures on topological spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure).

$^{[2]}$ As you rightfully point out in your comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Given any measure $m$ on a measurable space $(X, \Sigma)$, $m$ may always be extended to an outer measure $m^*$ with the prescription $m^*(E) = \inf \{ m(A): E \subset A, A \in \Sigma\}$.  Note that $m^*(\emptyset) = 0$ is clear since $\emptyset \in \Sigma$.  Further, $m^*$ is clearly monotonic.  The only real think to check is subadditivity.

Given a countable collection $\{A_k\}_k$ of subsets of $X$ and $\epsilon > 0$ (where we'll assume $m^*(A_k) < \infty$ for each k, else there's nothing to prove), we'll pick for each $k$ a set $E_k \in \Sigma$ containing $A_k$ such that $m^*(A_k) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^k} > m(E_k)$.  Then, if $A = \bigcup_k A_k$, we have that $\bigcup_k E_k \in \Sigma$ and contains $A$, so

$m^*(A) \le m(\bigcup_k E_k) \le \sum_k m(E_k) \le \sum_k m^*(A_k) + \epsilon$ and the result follows.

The last thing to show is that $m^* = m$ on $\Sigma$.  For that, we have for free that $m^*(E) \le m(E)$, for all $E \in \Sigma$ by definition of $m^*$.  Alternatively, if $\epsilon >0$, pick a set $E' \in \Sigma$ containing $E$ with $m^*(E) + \epsilon \ge m(E') \ge m(E)$ (the last inequality following by the monotonicity of $m$), and so we're done.

In this sense, there's really not much of a distinction between measures and outer measures, and many texts in geometric measure theory deal exclusively with outer measures for convenience.

Comment: That's not the one I'm looking for. I'm asking whether an outer-measure in the sense of Caratheodory satisfies the infimum property.

Comment: Take a similar example, the topological spaces could be defined through neighborhoods, see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Neighbourhoods_definition). One can omit the fourth axiom to define a topology, but one cannot reproduce the same system of neighborhoods if the fourth axiom is omitted.